# How to set debuggable property in kts build script

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I used this code in my module build script to set id release build is debbugable or not, but now `isDebbugable` is not working (Unresolved reference).

```
getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = rootProject.ext.get("debuggable_release") as Boolean
        }
```

What is the corresponding property for `debuggable` in kts

This option has disappeared after upgrading to **AGP 7.0**

Answer (score 2):

In .kts you can use `isDebuggable = true`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for that is to go back to the previous version of **AGP 4.2.0**
But there should be a better way to fix this